# Role Permissions in Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

Trying to lock a channel after an async sleep. I got the sleep but my 45 minute research has not helped at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `discord.TextChannel.set_permissions()` to target specific Members or Roles. (You can also iterate over all the roles in your guild.)

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.TextChannel.edit

If you are still stuck, show code of your attempt using that method.

Comment: `overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
            kwargs.overwrite.send_messages = False
            kwargs.overwrite.read_messages = True
            await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrite)`

Answer (score 0):

```
channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='Name')
await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```